# Is the Univers font free?

Tags: fonts

When we started up our company, our designer recommended the Univers LT STD Roman font, telling us it was free. Now, I've found numerous sites that sell it for money. So, I'm a bit confused. Is it free?

Comment: short answer: no.

Comment: Long answer: nooooooooo.

Comment: why was this downvoted? It seems to be a legitimate question. the op's designer is the one that made a mistake.

Answer (score 3):

Univers is owned and licensed by Linotype (the LT in the font name). It is not free. You can probably find it as a free download somewhere but you will be using it without a license.

There are a number of versions of Univers (the one you have there is Linotype Univers), none of which are free.

Answer (score 1):

The Univers LT STD Roman fonts are not free fonts. On www.fontsup.com free font downloads database there are 27 Univers LT STD Roman fonts listed and all of the fonts show a message in red letters that says: *Font has been removed by request of copyright owner*.

[image]